Max Geometric Sequences
We start with a number, say 12. Then try to find how many different 3-number geometric sequences exist below (up to and including) that number.
Ex: below 12, there are 4 such sets:
1,2,4,8 <---sum=15
1,3,9 <---sum=13
4,6,9 <---sum=19
3,6,12 <---sum=21  <--MAX

Then return the largest sum, in this case Max=21.
Is there an internal function to derive a Geometric sequence, or we have to devise one.
In this case:
F(12)=21

Need a generic definition for F(x) - Would be nice to list out the sequences!
Each sequence must have a minimum of 3 terms.
P.S. Observing the outputs for 12, I would suspect this is a build-up case. As in, a series of multiplications (1.5, 2, 2.5, etc...) from 1 and upwards, starting from various points, up until x. As long as the results are integers and minimal sets of 3. So the same sets are included in the output for 13 and upwards obviously and more! All the lower sets are inclusively included in the upper ones.

What do you mean by 3-number geometric sequence?

Hi @A. Kato : See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

A brute force method: bruteForce[n_] :=   MaximalBy[    Select[Subsets[Range@n, {3}], Differences@Ratios@# == {0} &],     Total] // First Finds the subset of 3 integers less than or equal to n that have constant ratio between them and maximal sum. Probably a much more elegant way to do this though.

Thanks @ydd  ...this is a great start, crashing over here (is late) will check in the morning)....if you get it to work let me know!

@Steve237 I know what geometric sequence means :-) From ydd's answer I learned your "3-number" means the length of the sequence. I am much confused because you showed 1,2,4,8 as example.

because it is MINIMUM 3 number sequence!

Add-on: After A little discussion with Steve, I believe we are looking for the largest sum geometric sequence with integer values that is at least 3 integers long. We can generalize my previous code to check up to which prime powers n is divisible by. If any of those generate a higher sum, we take that as the new sum. Otherwise we use the old result of n-1's best sum:
ClearAll["`*"]

(*max prime exponent*)
maxPrimePower[n_] := Max@FactorInteger[n][[All, 2]]
(*value of geometric sum*)
sumValue[r_, p_] := Sum[(r)^k, {k, 0, p}] // FullSimplify // Evaluate
(*max integer of the form z^k that divides n*)
maxKPowerDivisor[n_, k_] := Module[{primes, pows},
  {primes, pows} = Transpose@FactorInteger[n];
  pows = Quotient[pows, k];
  Times @@ MapThread[Power, {primes, pows}]
  ]

(*initialize with the best geometric sum for n=4*)
getMaxSumSeqAnyLength[4] = {1, 2, 4};
getMaxSumSeqAnyLength[n_ /; n >= 4] := 
 getMaxSumSeqAnyLength[n] = 
  Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, 
   Module[{bestSeq, maxSumSeen, maxXSeen, maxP, bestDivisors, 
     bestRList, sumValues, bestIndex, bestR},
    
    bestSeq = getMaxSumSeqAnyLength[n - 1];
    maxSumSeen = Total@bestSeq;
    maxXSeen = Last@bestSeq;
    
    maxP = maxPrimePower[n];
    
    If[maxP > 1,
     
     bestDivisors = maxKPowerDivisor[n, #] & /@ Range[2, maxP];
     bestRList = (bestDivisors - 1)/bestDivisors;
     sumValues = 
      n*MapIndexed[sumValue[#1, #2[[1]] + 1] &, bestRList];
     
     If[Max@sumValues > maxSumSeen,
      
      bestIndex = PositionLargest[sumValues, 1][[1, 1]];
      bestR = bestRList[[bestIndex]];
      bestSeq = n*(bestR^Range[0, bestIndex + 1]) // Reverse;
      ];
     
     ];
    bestSeq
    ]
   ]


So for example:
getMaxSumSeqAnyLength[1000]

(*{729, 810, 900, 1000}*)

returns a length 4 geometric sequence.
Note for really large n, this is a little finnicky. Calling getMaxSumSeqAnyLength[10000] for example right after definition will crash the kernel, but if we preload the downvalues in steps of 1000 we can evaluate it:
Table[getMaxSumSeqAnyLength[1000 n], {n, 10}];
getMaxSumSeqAnyLength[10000]

(*{6561, 7290, 8100, 9000, 10000}*)

I feel like there's something pretty basic I'm missing about recursive functions/memoization that should allow evaluation to happen without having to preload the downvalues in small steps.

Your geometric sum we want to maximize will look like (I am kind of thinking about this backwards, where we start at the maximum value of the sequence, and $r<1$ so we move down to next lowest value of the sequence):
$$
\begin{align}
x ~ (r^2 + r^1 + 1)\\ \\
r \in \mathbb{Q} ~\land ~ r < 1 \\ \\
x \in \mathbb{Z} ~\land ~1 \leq x \leq n
\end{align}
$$
Where $x$ is the starting point, and $r$ is the ratio of the geometric sequence.
Now expand $r$ with its integer numerator $a$ and denominator $d$:
$$
r = \frac{a}{d}
$$
In order for the smallest value of the sequence
$$
x r^2 = x\frac{ a^2}{d^2}
$$
to be an integer, $x$ must not be squarefree, and $x$ must be divisible by the square of $r$'s denominator $d^2$.
It also follows that since $d^2$ divides $x$, any integer value for the numerator $a$ will still make the sequence integer-valued. So we should pick $a$ to be as large as possible (to maximize our sum) while still having $r < 1$:
$$
a = d-1\\
r = \frac{d-1}{d}
$$
Since we want $r$ to be as close to 1 as possible, we select the biggest $d$ s.t. $d^2$ divides $n$.

As you pointed out, the geometric sequences all with values less than $n-1$ are part of the geometric sequences for $n$, so the maximum sum can never decrease. We also know that the largest value $x(n)$ of the maximum sum sequence for $n$ is bounded by:
$$
x(n-1) \leq x(n) \leq n
$$
And we know $x(n)$ is not squarefree, since it must be divisible by $d^2$. Since we know that all the previous values less than $n$ have been checked, we just need to check if $n$ is not squarefree, and then calculate if its sum
$$
n  \left(\left(\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^2 + \frac{d-1}{d} + 1\right)
$$
is larger than the previous best sum ending in $x(n-1)$, where $d$ is the largest integer such that $d^2$ divides $n$.

We can make a recursive function, where we iteravely round down the largest value in the geometric sequence $x$ to the nearest non-squarefree integer, find the largest square that is a divisor, and see if it does better than the previously best observed sequence:
ClearAll[getMaxSumSeq]

(*initialize with the best geometric sum for n=4*)
getMaxSumSeq[4] = {1, 2, 4};

getMaxSumSeq[n_ /; n >= 4] := 
 getMaxSumSeq[n] = 
  Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, 
   Module[{bestSeq, maxSumSeen, maxXSeen, x, d, r, testSeq, testSum},
    
    (*initialize bestSeq,maxSumSeen,
    maxNSeen as previous number's best sequence*)
    bestSeq = getMaxSumSeq[n - 1];
    maxSumSeen = Total@bestSeq;
    maxXSeen = Last@bestSeq;
    
    (*check if n has a square factor*)
    If[SquareFreeQ[n] == False,
     
     (*set x to n*)
     x = n;
     
     (*largest square divisor*)
     d = Last@Select[Sqrt@Divisors[x], IntegerQ];
     
     (*maximal geometric ratio*)
     r = (d - 1)/d;
     
     (*generate sequence*)
     testSeq = x*{r^2, r, 1};
     (*and sum*)
     testSum = Total@testSeq;
     
     (*compare to best sum seen so far,if the sum is larger,
     record the sequence as the best*)
     If[testSum > maxSumSeen,
      maxSumSeen = testSum;
      bestSeq = testSeq;
      ];
     ];
    
    (*output best sequence*)
    bestSeq]
   ]
    

Compare this to the brute force method:
bruteForce[n_] := 
 MaximalBy[
   Select[Subsets[Range@n, {3}], Differences@Ratios@# == {0} &], 
   Total] // First

getMaxSumSeq[100] // AbsoluteTiming
bruteForce[100] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.003176, {81, 90, 100}}*)
(*{0.216285, {81, 90, 100}}*)

And test for equality:
And @@ Table[bruteForce[n] == getMaxSumSeq[n], {n, 4, 100}]

(*True*)


If you are also interested in geometric sequences with lengths other than 3, we can use the same method. Suppose we want to maximize a geometric sequence of length $l$. We can write the sum as
$$
x \sum_{i=0}^{l-1} r^i = x \frac{ r^l-1}{r-1}
$$
We can show like before that $d^{l-1}$ must divide $x$, and in order to maximize the sum $a = d^{l-1} -1$. We now just check if $n$ has a prime exponent greater than or equal to $l-1$, find all the maximum $d_k$ such that $d_1^2, d_2^3, ..., d_{l-2}^{l-1}$ divide $n$, and (if it's larger than the previous best sum) return the sequence that gives the largest sum.

You assume that the length of wanted geometric sequence is always three. It is not clear from OP's question that this is what he requires or not. (Of course it is not your responsibility :-)

Ah. Well In the case of longer sequences (I.e. length $l$ sequences), you want to pick the largest divisor $d$ s.t. $d^{l-1} \mid n$. You can filter out the $n$ beforehand by only selecting ones with at least one prime factor power greater than $l-1$ (so kind of a generalization I guess of non-squarefree numbers to non-(l-1)powerfree numbers)

You're completely right. Thank you.

Hi @ydd : Brilliant solution, absolutely elegant! Thanks....!   by the way My original intent was to get the result for 1000 --> getMaxSumSeq[1000]  but that is giving me Recursion Limit!   letting BruteForce do that but it is taking long!

Brute force came back, a few min later for 1000 ==>  {900, 930, 961}

I tried these, none work!   Block[{$RecursionLimit=Infinity},CODE]

Hi @ydd:  for 1,000 bruteforce gives {900,930,961} -- but here is a larger one:  729 810 900 1000  r=10/9 and total SUM is greater!

Fix would be Subsets[Range@n, {3, 4}] or even more like 5, 6, etc...but memory fails even at 4

I added a Block with infinite recursion that works for n=1000 (though it appears to still fail once you get to around n = 10000). For the other comment, I think I misunderstood the problem; do you want the integer-valued geoemetric sequence with largest sum that is at least 3 long?

Yes at least 3 long....so can even be 10 or 15 long!  i want n=1000, not 10,000   so for the brute force method, to get >=3 member, we can put like:  Subsets[Range@n, {3, n}]  where n=4,5,6....  but that will blow up the mem - How would you change your other algo to account for >= 3 ?

@Steve237 I updated my answer to give the max sum sequence with length at least 3. As far as modifying the brute force approach to work, you could use SelectSubsets to reduce memory pressure:
`SelectSubsets = ResourceFunction["SelectSubsets"]
candSubs[n_] := With[{maximalSubsetLength = 1 + Floor[Log2[n]]},
SelectSubsets[Range@n, {3, maximalSubsetLength},
Norm[Differences@Ratios@#] == 0 &]
]
bruteForce[n_] := With[{subs = candSubs[n]},
MaximalBy[subs, Total] // First
] but now it's so slow that it's not really useful forn` much greater than 30.

Thanks looks good, Why didn't you just set getMaxSumSeqAnyLength[n_ /; n >= 3] instead of >=4

Note n here is not the length of the sequence, it is the maximum value the sequence can have. E.g. in the example in your question, $n=12$.  There are no geometric integer sequences with length at least 3 unless $n \geq 4$ (the first non-squarefree integer) so that is why I have that condition.
